# Can I use only one request to fill the same html element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, user-interface, request, element

I'm using ajax to make a request to a webservice.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var token = "123";
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST", //REQUEST TYPE
        dataType: "json", //RESPONSE TYPE
        url: "http://ws/mehtod"+token, 
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data, function(i) {
                    $('#list_countries').append("<option>" + data[i].Name + "</option>"); //fILL THE DDL. FOR EACH ITEM RETURNED ADD DATA[NAME] TO ONE LINE OF THE DDL.-
            });
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
    }).always(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus != "success") {
            alert("Error: " + jqXHR.statusText);
        }
    })
});
```

and the question is: I have multiple elements in my html that have the ID "list_countries" (they're all the same element but in different panels inside the page) and my rerquest works and treats the data well but for some reason it only fills one of the elements. The others don't fill with the data requested. What can be the cause of this?? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It's not valid in HTML to have more than one element with the same I'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because you use **identificator #list_countries multiple times**. Better use class selector or unical ids:

```
$('#list_countries, #list_countries_2, #list_countries_3');
// or
$('.list_countries');
```

Comment: Thank you friend! That solved my problem, i've just switched it to class. But can you explain me why does class selectors work and ids don't?

Comment: HTML validation rule. That's the whole idea that id - is always unical identificator, that can be only one. CSS ignore that rule, but not javascript.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You've helped me a lot. Very thank you bud. +1

Answer (score 1):

> Try This:

```
$('#list_countries').each(function() {
    $(this).append("<option>" + data[i].Name + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: @elegan-user Thank you but I've already solved my problem switching my ids to classes.

Answer (score 1):

The selector that you're using tells jQuery to internelly use the native `document.getElementById()` method for fetching the DOM wich returns **ONLY the first node** which appears in the page that matches the selector regardless to any other node(s) with the same `ID`.
So, you have to enforce jQuery to **NOT** use the native `document.getElementById()` method and here's a trick for you:

```
$.each(data, function(i) {
    $('body #list_countries').append("<option>" + data[i].Name + "</option>");
});
```

Note the `body` before `#list_countries`, here we enforce it to use the Sizzle for this job instead of `document.getElementById()` method.

**PS:** I strongly suggest that you use the same `class` for different elements instead of the `ID` which must be unique in the page.